# Automate Importing PST in Outlook for All Users in a Company

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange, pst

My company has just moved stored PSTs (not the server, just the PSTs I believe) from 1 remote server to another (literally copy and pasted). Let's call the old server \\oldserver and the new server \\newserver. The PSTs are stored in the exact same hierarchy in both servers. The only difference in path is the name of the server.

I've been instructed to set appointments with each person at the company (over 100 people) in order to point their Outlook 2007 data files to \\newserver\pst[username], as all of them on all machines are currently pointed to \\oldserver\pst[username].

I'm an IT guy, not the exchange administrator, so I can't really do anything via the Exchange server. There has to be a better way of doing this than what I was told to do: i.e. Manually going to each person, opening up mail data files, removing the old path, adding the new path, verifying it worked, and rebooting. All I need to do is change that path from \oldserver to \newserver.

Any help would be graciously appreciated!

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: While that is the case, I wonder if this is an acceptable exception? He's under direction from IT, he has a specific need clearly stated, this information may be useful to others, and he's looking to further his technical capability to accomplish a difficult task in a better way.

Comment: @music2myear: That's exactly the case. I have instructions on how to do it, I'm just seeing if it's more efficient. I've searched for an answer, but no resource has an explanation for multiple users. Therefore, this information would be beneficial to others who may have the same issue.

Comment: You can specify this sort of thing via Group Policy, you could also force it via a repair install with the updated path in the configuration I believe. What I'm not certain of is whether this can be scripted in any way. If the paths are stored in registry, it would be trivial to update or change this information. But I'm not certain that is the case.

Comment: Do you mean a repair install of Outlook? Is there any resource you can point me to that explains how to do this via the group policy?

Thank you for helping me by the way!